# ORA-12154 TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified with SQLPLUS

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, connectivity

I am using Toad to connect my database and its working fine for me .
But when i try to connect with the same credential , i am getting the error message as shown below:

```
ORA-12154 TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

Steps:

1. Opened command promt
2. Reach to the path of SQLPLUS (*C:\programs\Oracle\Ora11g\BIN*)
3. C:\programs\Oracle\Ora11g\BIN\sqlplus username@schema_name
4. Enter Password :

   ERROR:
    ORA-12154 TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified
5. But when i open this with the owner of the schema ,it works for me
6. C:\programs\Oracle\Ora11g\BIN\sqlplus schema_name@schema_name
7. Enter Password:
8. Connected to :......................

So,my question is why my username is not able to connect that particular schema ,while the owner of that schema can connect .
Note:I can connect to that schema with my username with Toad ,but not with sqlplus

My `TNSNAME.ORA` is under `TNS_ADMIN` folder

Please help me out of this .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually through toad you are able to login because `ORACLE_HOME` was set there. but once you're trying to use `$ORACLE_HOME/bin`, your home is not set properly.

To resolve this, first export `$ORACLE_HOME` and `$ORACLE_SID` then try, it should be fine.

Answer (score 4):

So you don't need to specify the full path when you run `sqlplus.exe`:

Set your `%TNS_ADMIN%` variable to  the full path of the relevant folder (`C:\programs\Oracle\Ora11g\TNS_ADMIN` ?). Instructions for doing so are a google away.  At the same time, make sure `%ORACLE_HOME%` is set to `C:\programs\Oracle\Ora11g` and that your `%PATH%` has `C:\programs\Oracle\Ora11g\bin` added to it.

The problem you're actually having is because of the parameters you're passing to sqlplus.

You've been doing:

```
C:\programs\Oracle\Ora11g\BIN\sqlplus username@schema_name
```

Which is wrong & interpreted by sqlplus as:

```
C:\programs\Oracle\Ora11g\BIN\sqlplus username@database_name
```

Also, in Oracle, the owner of a schema (hence the schema name) is the user name. Obviously, grants can be given to other users to perform DML/DDL on other schemas, but you still have to login with a user with sufficient rights. (Proxy logins exist, as does `alter session set current_schema=blah`, but both are beyond the scope of this answer).

Comment: :Sorry for your time,but my problem is with my password ,that contain `@` and thats why its giving me this error .@ is read as special character in sqlplus,it try to open something ..

Comment: Like Gaurav Soni, I've also seen this issue caused by a password containing an '@'. Either: 1. Change the password or 2. When you enter it interactively in sqlplus, add a double-quote to the beginning and end of the password.